# Extracting data in a particular Format

Tags: csv, format

I have gene.csv file which is about 1.3 GB in size and has got 300 columns and more than a million rows. it looks like following,

```
id1      id2    id3    id4         count1      count2
S1001    450    GAF    ARHGAP18    1.56E-05    1483
S1001    450    GAF    ARHGAP12    5E-05       3698
S1001    450    GAF    ARHGAP15    2.75E-06    93
S1001    450    GAF    ARHGAP17    3E-05       1889
S1001    450    GAF    ARHGAP19    4.291E-06   596
S1002    450    GAF    ARHGAP18    5.955E-05   5353
S1002    450    GAF    ARHGAP12    8.578E-08   14
S1002    450    BAF    ARHGAP15    2.91E-05    5381
S1002    450    BAF    ARHGAP17    1.78E-06    105
S1002    450    BAF    ARHGAP19    3.62E-05    5764
S1003    450    BAF    ARHGAP18    5.2697E-06  330
S1003    450    BAF    ARHGAP12    5.955E-05   2263
S1003    450    BAF    ARHGAP15    8.578E-08   3147
S1003    450    CAF    ARHGAP17    2.91E-05    50
S1003    450    CAF    ARHGAP19    5.955E-05   1595
S1004    450    CAF    ARHGAP18    8.578E-08   970
S1004    450    CAF    ARHGAP12    2.91E-05    816
S1004    450    CAF    ARHGAP15    5.955E-05   4981
S1004    450    CAF    ARHGAP17    8.578E-08   816
S1004    450    CAF    ARHGAP19    2.91E-05    4981
```

I want only id1. id4 and count2 data fetched in the following format (as a matrix)

```
id4        S1001   S1002 S1003  S1004
ARHGAP18    1483   5353  330    970
ARHGAP12    3698   14    2263   816
ARHGAP15    93     5381  3147   4981
ARHGAP17    1889   105   50     816
ARHGAP19    596    5764  1595   4981
```

I need id1 as column ids(Repeated only once).

Comment: So... what's the programming related question here? Looks like you haven't even started, or maybe that's just missing from the question?

Comment: Thanks, James, you are right, Its nothing to do with Programming so i have not started it! But i was expecting a simple programming help would be of some help.Thanks for you help !

Comment: Well, there's plenty of ways to do this, but you haven't mentioned anything, for example the language / tools you're planning to use.

Comment: James, I am a Biologist, and I got this file to analyze, I have some experience with shell and R but I am not a programmer or expert like you guys. So to seek solution i logged into Stack..